# Resolving TCM links in Rich Text

Tags: content-manager, sdl-tridion, link-resolver

One of my components uses a link of the form " Data Logger". Tell me, please, in which direction should I think to get the url of this component instead of "tcm: 74-217224" when publishing component (using TBB) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a TBB you can read component links as

```
<a tridion:href="@@Component.Fields.xmlnameofComponentLinkField@@" 
    target="_blank" title="This is my Component Link">
    This is my Component Link
</a>
```

please go through [this](https://tridionbasicscity.com/2015/05/05/tcdl-tridion-content-deployment-language-basics-i/) link once